# How to search for Event Custom fields?

Tags: civievent

Civi4.6.4 WP 4.2.2
I have a custom field for all Event Types called "Featured"(yes/no).  We will have many events created and only a few will be "Featured"(Yes).  So is there a way in the Manage Event List to search for just the "Featured" Events?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new report, go to Reports->Event Reports, click on New Event Report, Select  Income Count Summary Report, you can customize the report and if the featured field is searchable you will find it here. Hope this helps

Comment: Ok... that kinda helps.  However, it would be really cool if I could search for the "Featured" Events in the Manage Event Search area!

Comment: you can create the report and add it to the menu as a child of Manage events